# Alight text in header using custom.css in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i just want to center my menu in my header .

My website : http://test.projekt-tenis.pl/wordpress/

and my header now looks like :[image]
All i want to do is just center my menu it's little  too left . How can i center it using only wp-admin and custom.css .
I try to use google edit :[image]
but can't find solution all the time i move all the menu to left cac't just center it. Can enyone help? and i just want to align social icon to right but don't know why i have so much space beetwen them like this :
[image]

**EDIT 1**
I add what you wrote but its looks like the same check it :[image] i just want do delete space beetween facebook icon and linked in icon want the same like next to twitter and linked in.
And as i said i need to center my menu when you open my site you gonna see main menu : Główna , Oferta etc. Is not in the center its little paddig do left i want to center it using custom.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is not properly written so there is no proper way (I'm aware of) to centre Navigation by using proper CSS. However, navigation can be centered by adjusting margin/padding but it's **Not Recommended**

So, you would **need to make changes** in HTML code: (**Recommended**)

**How:**

1. Create 3 separate `div's` for (Logo, Nav and Social)
2. Assign specific width (according to your needs)
3. Add css property to align left: `float: left;`
4. Finally, apply `text-align: center;` to Navigation

**Example:**

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
}

#container div{
  float: left;
}

#logo, #social{
  width: 15%;
}

#nav{
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo">
    LOGO
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    NAVIGATION ITEMS
  </div>

  <div id="social">
    SOCIAL
  </div>

</div>
```

And there is extra padding applied to one of social media icon and you can fix in two different ways:

**1.** Find below piece of code and change `padding-right: 10px` to `padding-right: 0px`

**Old:** (Currently, look like this)

```
.primary-menu li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

**New:** (Should look like)

```
.primary-menu li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

**2.** Add below code in `custom.css` or other styles file.

```
.primary-menu li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

**NOTE:**

- First method is the **Best** and **Recommended** way
- The second method is **not recommended**. I just mentioned because you looks beginner so maybe you'll have some difficulties in locating original style and in that case, you can try 2nd solution.

Comment: Check my edit just if you can :)

Comment: the answer is updated

Comment: thank you for your ansear  it's correct but the problem is i don't have acces to files. I can only use custom css to do that . Can you just help me with using only custom css? :(

Comment: Add this to `custom.css`, `.primary-menu ul { padding: 0 0 0 135px; }` This will approximately center the navigation. And don't forget to accept the answer!